# Recycler's view custom layout manager animation

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-recyclerview

According to the [Building a RecyclerView LayoutManager article](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2014/09/building-a-recyclerview-layoutmanager-part-1/) I have created own custom layout manager for RecyclerView, but due to a few documentation available i can't find a way to force recycle view rebuild animation inside from layout manager ( just like animations when notifyItemInserted or notifyItemDeleted is used). Such animations are controlled by recyclerView and its item animators, developer only can control position of items.
So i have a method `fill`, which performs placing child views according to current scroll position and state of layout manager. Such method is called from two places,

- in onLayoutChildren ( this method is called when layout manager performs initialization placing of items or when data set was changed)

  ```
  @Override
  public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
     detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
     fill(recycler);
  }
  ```
- in scrollVerticallyBy

  ```
  /** calculate offset of views while scrolling, layout items on new places*/
  @Override
  public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
      dy = scrollVerticallyInternal(dy);
      offsetChildrenVertical(-dy);
      if (condition) {
          //todo refactor it, blinking now without animation. 
          detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);
      }

      fill(recycler);
      return dy;
  }
  ```

And i want in case of some `condition` perform a bit more complex transition for some views and with animation.
 
It may be reached if somehow initiate layouting childrens flow, when `onLayoutChildren` method will be invoked by RecyclerView.
I'm able to do this with `detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler)` and that initiates `onLayoutChildren` and running default `fill` process, but such transition will be performed instantly without any animation.

Is it possible to force recyclerView (or layout manager) inside from layout manager to run its animations?

Comment: reason of downvote? Please post comments in such cases guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've investigated the source of `RecyclerView` and found that `onLayoutChildren` is called when `RecyclerView` performs own layouting process. So calling `requestLayout` should be an option, instead of `detachAndScrapAttachedViews`. And with combination of `requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout` it should helps. But NOT. 
Those operations would work only if been performed inside `postOnAnimation` runnable. So, at least, with my completed `scrollVerticalBy` my layout manager've been running animations successfully:

```
@Override
public int scrollVerticallyBy(int dy, RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
    dy = scrollVerticallyInternal(dy);
    offsetChildrenVertical(-dy);
    postOnAnimation(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            requestLayout();
            requestSimpleAnimationsInNextLayout();
        }
    });

    fill(recycler);
    return dy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we have implemented a custom LayoutManager, we also made our own animation for ExpandLayoutManager. In particular, we have used ValueAnimator for animating changes of the LayoutManager look. If you’re curious about our ExpandLayoutManager, it’s available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azoft/ExpandLayoutManager/blob/master/LayoutManager/expandlayoutmanager/src/main/java/com/azoft/expandlayoutmanager/model/SimpleExpandModel.java#L313).

Here you can also find some valuable details for creating custom LayoutManagers: http://cases.azoft.com/create-custom-layoutmanager-android/